# Issue with Bootstrap 4 after migration to Angular rc5 from rc beta

Tags: angular, angular2-directives, bootstrap-4

I have migrating my angular application from Beta version to Angular rc5.
and i am getting following errors when tried to add any bootstrap control in component.

> (index):48 Error: (SystemJS) No Directive annotation found on
>   Dropdown(…)(anonymous function) @ (index):48ZoneDelegate.invoke @
>   zone.js:332Zone.run @ zone.js:225(anonymous function) @
>   zone.js:591ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ zone.js:365Zone.runTask @
>   zone.js:265drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone.js:497ZoneTask.invoke @
>   zone.js:437

[image]

Also got same error for DropDown,Collapse and Alert

**App.module.ts code**

```
import {HeaderComponent} from './scripts/common/header.component';
import {MyProfileComponent} from './scripts/my-profile/my-profile.component';
import {SecurityService} from './scripts/services/security.service';
import {Configuration} from "./app.contstants";
import {FormBuilder, Validators, Control, ControlGroup, FORM_DIRECTIVES} from '@angular/common';
import {EventEmitterComponent}from "./scripts/common/event-emitter.component";
@NgModule({

    declarations: [MyProfileComponent, HeaderComponent],
  imports     : [BrowserModule, FormsModule, HttpModule, RouterModule.forRoot(rootRouterConfig)],
  providers: [{ provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy }, HttpModule, SecurityService, Configuration, FormBuilder, EventEmitterComponent, TranslateService, TranslateLoader],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],

})
export class AppModule {

}
```

**header.component.ts**

```
import { Dropdown,DROPDOWN_DIRECTIVES } from 'ng2-bootstrap/ng2-bootstrap';
import {CrudService} from '../../crud.service';

@Component({
    selector: '.app-header',
    templateUrl: 'assets/scripts/common/header.html',
    directives: [CORE_DIRECTIVES, FORM_DIRECTIVES, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, Collapse,JQueryComponent,RouterLink],
    providers: [CrudService],
```

Please help me to resolve this problem.

Thanks in advance,
Swapnil K.
    pipes: [TranslatePipe , SearchPipe]
})

Comment: Your image of text [isn't very helpful](//meta.unix.stackexchange.com/q/4086).  It can't be copied into an editor, and it doesn't index very well, meaning that other users with the same problem are less likely to find the answer here.  Please [edit] your post to incorporate the relevant text directly (preferably using copy+paste to avoid transcription errors).

Comment: Does my answer help?

Comment: @JohnSiu : No, i tried it . but still facing same error.

Comment: I properly need a github repo to test it out.

Answer (score 1):

In `App.modules.ts`, there is no AppComponent import.
In `header.component.ts`, `directives` and `providers` should be moved to `App.module.ts`.

**App.module.ts**

```
import {AppComponent} from '<PATH FOR AppComponent>'; // <---- Import AppComponent

import {HeaderComponent} from './scripts/common/header.component';
import {MyProfileComponent} from './scripts/my-profile/my-profile.component';
import {SecurityService} from './scripts/services/security.service';
import {Configuration} from "./app.contstants";
import {FormBuilder, Validators, Control, ControlGroup, FORM_DIRECTIVES} from '@angular/common';
import {EventEmitterComponent}from "./scripts/common/event-emitter.component";

// Moved from HeaderComponent
import { Dropdown, DROPDOWN_DIRECTIVES } from 'ng2-bootstrap/ng2-bootstrap';
import {CrudService} from '../../crud.service';


@NgModule({

    declarations: [
        MyProfileComponent,
        HeaderComponent],
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        FormsModule,
        HttpModule,
        RouterModule.forRoot(rootRouterConfig)],
    // directives moved from HeaderComponent
    directives: [
        CORE_DIRECTIVES,
        FORM_DIRECTIVES,
        ROUTER_DIRECTIVES,
        Collapse,
        JQueryComponent,
        RouterLink],
    providers: [
        { provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy },
        HttpModule,
        SecurityService,
        Configuration,
        FormBuilder,
        EventEmitterComponent,
        TranslateService,
        TranslateLoader,
        CrudService],   // service moved from HeaderComponent
    bootstrap: [
        AppComponent],

})
export class AppModule { }
```

**header.component.ts**

```
@Component({
    selector: '.app-header',
    templateUrl: 'assets/scripts/common/header.html'})
```